# Bug in Chrome? Drag feedback on links misaligned

Tags: google-chrome, hyperlink, drag-and-drop, draggable

If I create a link with the attribute "draggable" and then drag the link, Chrome displays an image of the link that follows the mouse cursor. In some cases, notably when there is distance between the link and the left boundary of its parent node, the dragged image ends up at a constant distance from the mouse cursor.

Why is it that the partially transparent image does not line up with the mouse cursor in Chrome? It seems to work fine in Firefox and Opera. Is this a bug, and is there a fix?

See a very simple example here: http://jsfiddle.net/mjbCN/1/

Comment: This issue is also the case when every item has different ID's too.

Comment: I found that if I style the links as "display: inline-block" it works correctly. This is a suitable workaround for me, but it still seems like a bug.

Answer (score 0):

This was eventually fixed, apparently.

https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=101204